# How to pass to the variable the Auth::user() method and sync into pivot table?

Tags: php, laravel, synchronization, laravel-5, pivot-table

I can get the current user that logged in. But I don't know how can I passed this into variable. I can the user id by this.

```
public function getDocuments()
{
    //GETTING ALL THE ID OF THE USERS IN THE DATABASE EXCEPT THE ID OF CURRENT USER.
    $resultRecipient = DB::table('users')->where('id', '!=', Auth::id())->get();


    //GETTING ALL THE CATEGORIES.
    $resultCategory = DB::table('categories')->get();


    //VIEW
    return view ('document.create')->with('resultRecipient', $resultRecipient)->with('resultCategory', $resultCategory);

    if(\Auth::user()->id)
    {
        echo "You get the id";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Failed";
    }

}
```

Can anyone tell me how can I sync the current user id when the submit button is submitted. Is there a way how can I attach the id of the user in the sync method?

```
public function postDocuments(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request,
    [
        'title' => 'required|alpha_dash|max:255',
        'content' => 'required',
        'category_id' => 'required',
        'recipient_id' => 'required',
    ]);


    $document = new Document();
                                //Request in the form
    $document->title = $request->title;
    $document->content = $request->content;
    $document->category_id = $request->category_id;

    $document->save();
    $document->recipients()->sync($request->recipient_id, false);

    return redirect()->back();  
}
```

**UPDATE!**

According to @Ariful. I can add the instance of `Auth::user();` to get the id. But it doesn't return me the id to my pivot table and gives me a error.

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`webdev`.`document_user`, CONSTRAINT `document_user_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `document_user` (`document_id`, `user_id`) values (59, 0))

```
public function postDocuments(Request $request)
{

    $this->validate($request,
    [
        'title' => 'required|alpha_dash|max:255',
        'content' => 'required',
        'category_id' => 'required',
        'recipient_id' => 'required',
    ]);


    $user = Auth::user();
    $document = new Document();
                                //Request in the form
    $document->title = $request->title;
    $document->content = $request->content;
    $document->category_id = $request->category_id;

    $document->save();
    $document->recipients()->sync([$request->recipient_id, $user->id, false]);

    return redirect()->back();  
}
```

Models:

User Model

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract
{
  public function documents()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Document', 'document_user', 'user_id', 'document_id');
   }
}
```

Document Model:

```
class Document extends Model
{
  public function recipients()
  {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\User', 'document_user', 'document_id', 'user_id');
  }
}
```

Migration:

User migration

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('first_name');
        $table->string('last_name');
        $table->string('middle_name');
        $table->string('email');
        $table->string('username');
        $table->string('address');
        $table->string('password');
     });
 }
```

Documents migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('documents', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('title');
        $table->text('content');
        $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
        $table->foreign('category_id')->references('id')->on('categories')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

documents_user migration:

```
 public function up()
 {
    Schema::create('document_user',function (Blueprint $table)
    {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->integer('document_id')->unsigned();

        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('document_id')->references('id')->on('documents')->onDelete('cascade');

        $table->unsignedInteger('sender_id')->nullable();
        $table->foreign('sender_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');


        $table->dateTime('dateReceived')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
    });
 }
```

Screenshot Database:

[image: SC]

UPDATE 2:

I can insert a values on my user_id based on the user's choice in the select list.

This is where the values of the form inserted in the `user_id` column. I just need to insert the current user in my `sender_id` so I can determined who send the data.

```
<div class = "form-group">

        <label for = "recipient_id" class = "control-label">To:</label>

        <select name = "recipient_id[]" multiple class = "form-control" id = "myUserList">

            @foreach ($resultRecipient as $list)
                <option value = "{{ $list->id }}">{{ $list->username }}</option>
            @endforeach

    </select>

</div>
```

[image: SC]

As you can see here I just insert this manually based on the **users** table data. Still don't have idea how can I insert the current user into `sender_id` column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should work

```
$user = Auth::user(); //get current user

$document->recipients()->sync([$user->id]);
```

**UPDATED** [Source Link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/saving-additional-data-into-pivot-table)

```
$document->recipients()->sync( [ $request->recipient_id, $user->id ], false );
```

As per [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#inserting-many-to-many-relationships),

> The `sync` method accepts an array of IDs to place on the intermediate table.

**UPDATE 2**

```
$document->recipients()->sync( [ $request->recipient_id => 
                                     ['sender_id' => $user->id] ], 
                                     false );
```

Your `sender_id` is not part of your relationship. So you need to add it as extra info.

**UPDATE 3**

After discussion, this should be your main code

```
foreach($request->recipient_id as $receipentId){

    $document->recipients()->sync( [ $receipentId => 
                                 ['sender_id' => $user->id] ], 
                                 false );
}
```

This will loop through your `receipent_id` array and take each id for sync with the current logged in user as `$user->id`;

Comment: I can't get the user `id` after hitting the submit I tried to add in my `sync` method the `$request->recipient_id`. But it say's `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1452 Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`webdev`.`document_user`, CONSTRAINT `document_user_user_id_foreign` FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE) (SQL: insert into `document_user` (`document_id`, `user_id`) values (59, 0))`
Please see my updated post. :)

Comment: I also included my migrations. :)

Comment: it seems you are passing additional data with the `id`'s.. to sent additional data with id, you can try the updated code. Source link also provided.

Comment: Ohh your data received is `TIMESTAMP`, then whats the `false` in your sync function? if it is `$detaching` parameter, then that should be 2nd parameter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118077/discussion-between-ariful-haque-and-francisunoxx).

Comment: Chat your already please see my message and I update my post. :)

Comment: Don't mind the `TIMESTAMP` it works properly. I followed you code attach `$user->id` in the sync method. But it says. `Namespace declaration statement has to be the very first statement in the script`

Comment: Ya, I realized `TIMESTAMP` is not an issue. Please check the UPDATE 2

Comment: I run your code but it says. `preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array` I reference my `user_id` to `sender_id` just to make sure who send the data. Am I correct?

Comment: Lets use this [discussion](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118077/discussion-between-ariful-haque-and-francisunoxx) to talk and solve this.

Comment: Sure. Thank you for the responding.